# how to insert html after a specific element with a class using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <div class="carousel-inner">
     <!-- my jQuery content here -->
 <a data-slide="prev" href="#quote-carousel" class="left carousel-control"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>
 </div>
```

I am producing an html snippet and wanted to know how I can insert the html within the DIV tags shown above. Specifically immediately after the **div class="carousel-inner"** and before the **a data-slide**

I tried using

```
 $('body').append(html);
```

but that added the html to the end of the file

Comment: `$('div.carousel-inner').prepend(html);` but a simple search would have told you that. http://jsfiddle.net/xtb51wed/

Comment: You should look at the jQuery Docs before you post a question. Most of the names are quite intuitive. http://api.jquery.com/
Hint: prepend.

Comment: Time to start reading the api docs before asking questions. You are expected to have done some research before posting here

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the proper `selector` and use [insertBefore](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) in this situation to target `before the a data-slide:`

`$(yourHTML).insertBefore(".carousel-inner a[data-slide]");`

Comment: You need to call insertBefore like this: `$(yourHTML).insertBefore(".carousel-inner a[data-slide]");` http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/ or use before like: `$(".carousel-inner a[data-slide]").before(yourHTML);`

Comment: @jcubic whoops my bad. edited :)

Answer (score 0):

Use prepend

```
$('.carousel-inner').prepend('<div id="new_div">New div here</div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

[append is insert as last child](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

[prepend is insert as first child](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

greetings timotheus